# Setting All Vendor Prefixed Versions of "width: calc..." With jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, vendor-prefix

I'm working on using a project which uses jQuery, and I need to dynamically set a calc() based width using jQuery. The problem is that for calc to work, the CSS needs to look something like this:

**CSS**

```
width: -moz-calc(33% - 50px);
width: -webkit-calc(33% - 50px);
width: calc(33% - 50px);
```

When I try to use jQuery `$(selector).css('width', 'calc(33% - 50px)')`, I can't set width with multiple vendor prefixed versions of calc. What's the right way to handle multiple settings of the same CSS property in jQuery, to allow for vendor-prefixing?

Comment: I would add a new css hook. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
calc = "calc(33% - 50px)";

if ($.browser.webkit) {
  calc = "-webkit-"+calc;
}

$(selector).css('width',calc);
```

Comment: Browser sniffing is a horrible, horrible idea. There are variants of WebKit, some of which may support -webkit-calc and some not, some now but not in the future, some with additional features such as attr() inside calc and some not, etc. etc. Until Modernizr supports a variation of its 'prefixed' capability which handles calc, I would recommend setting the property with each prefixed variant of calc, then reading back the value to see if it "took", in which case you can be confident that browser supports the version of calc you through at it.